# Moving buttons in a webpage to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, button

I am trying to make the buttons to get to move. Like, when i click on a button, the button should move with an animation from one place to another.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<head>
<style>
* @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
}
@keyframes heading
{
    from {top:350px;}
    to   {top:300px;}
}
@keyframes quote
{
    from {top:290px}
    to {top: 240px}
}
@keyframes button
{
    from {opacity: 0}
    to {opacity: 1}
}
@keyframes mvbut
{
    from {top: 266px; right: 185px}
    to {top: 250px; right: 170px;}
}
.button
{
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    padding: 16px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.button1
{
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid white;
    position: relative;
    top : 266px;
    right: 185px;
    border-radius: 30px 7px;
    display:block;
    margin: auto;
    opacity: 0;
    animation-name: button;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-delay: 2s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.button1:hover
{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
.button3:click
{
    animation-name: mvbut;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.button2
{
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid white;
    position: relative;
    top : 210px;
    left: 0px;
    border-radius: 30px 7px;
    display:block;
    margin: auto;
    opacity: 0;
    animation-name: button;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-delay: 2.3s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.button2:hover
{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
.button3
{
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid white;
    position: relative;
    top : 154px;
    left: 185px;
    border-radius: 30px 7px;
    display:block;
    margin: auto;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 0;
    animation-name: button;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-delay: 2.6s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.button3:hover
{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
@font-face 
{
    font-family: beatsurge;
    src: url(neutronium.ttf);
}
p.border 
{
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    padding: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50px 20px;
    position: absolute;
}
body
{
    background-image: url("background.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
h1
{
    color: white;
    font-family: beatsurge;
    font-size: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 350px;
    left: 0px;
    position: relative;
    animation-name: heading;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-delay: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;  

}
p
{
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    top: 290px;
    left: 0px;
    animation-name: quote;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-delay: 1.25s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
</style>
<title>Beat Surge</title>
</head>
<body>
<div><h1><strong>BEAT SURGE</strong></h1></div>
<p>
Where words fail, music speaks.
</p>
<button class = "button button1">Remixes</button>
<button class = "button button2">Original Content</button>
<button class = "button button3">About Us</button>
</body>
</html>
```

For example, when i click on "Remixes", the button should move at the bottom left corner.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You are more likely to get help. Asking people to go inspect elements on your site to get the code so they can help you, is asking quite a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
   function movebutton() {
        document.getElementById("button1").style.top = "400px";
        document.getElementById("button1").style.left = "30px";
    }
```

```css
button{
  position: absolute;
  top:30px;
  left:400px;
  transition: 0.5s linear;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Beat Surge</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id = "button1" onclick="movebutton()">Remixes</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That didnt work. Can you show me a jsfiddle demo please? Thank you for replying

Comment: oh my code had syntax errors i'm so sorry, now it should work (i submitted  a demo) :D

Comment: How do i move a group of buttons with the same animation when i press one button?

Comment: you can add code to the movebutton function to modify other buttons (or any element) attribute like i did with "button1"

Comment: Perfect! Exactly What i wanted! Thank you ^_^

Comment: My heading (beat surge) wont go down. although it moves sideways. any ideas? no change in code other than adding than javascript code which you gave

Comment: set the position of the <strong> or the <h1> element from relative to absolute and reposition it

Comment: wops my bad , didn't see the div before the h1 tag, so you need to do it with the div element not the h1 or strong

Comment: Found the error. Error was with animation-fill-mode. When set to forwards, doesnt move when i try to change position. When i removed forward, it moves. But now my animation resets

Answer (score 1):

You can do this a number of ways. For the sake of a simple solution I have used `margin-left` and a simple `toggleClass`

Another alternative could be using absolute positioning or jquery animations.

```js
var _box = $('.box');

_box.on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('move');
});
```

```css
.box {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.box:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box.move {
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should really provide more information in your question, but: if I were doing this, I would give the button a click listener function that added a css class, and then use css to deal with element placement. Use css transitions for your animation.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', move);

function move(e) {
  e.target.classList.toggle('moved');
}
```

```css
button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40vh;
  left: 40vw;
  transition: all .2s;
}

.moved {
  top: 80vh;
  left: 4vw;
}
```

```html
<button>Clicky</button>
```

Comment: Worked. How do i move a group of buttons with the same animation?

Comment: There are a lot of options. If they'll always move together, stick them in a `div` and apply the css to the div. Note that in my function I used `e.target` to select the element to change class on. That wouldn't really work for a div, so you would want to use a more universal selector, like the `querySelector` I used on the first line.